# Simple netcat Responder

Tags: bash, netcat, nc

Trying to create a simple netcat responder:

The "server" would be:

```
$ while true; do { ./secret.sh; } | sudo netcat -k -q -1 -l 123; done
```

`secret.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
read line
if [ "$line" == "open" ]; then
    echo "sesame"
fi
```

And the client connection:

```
$ echo "open" | netcat localhost 123
```

It's not working as expected. What can be changed to make this work?

After reading some feedback elsewhere, the following changes were suggested:

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
while true; do { cat /tmp/pipe | ./secret.sh 2>&1; } | netcat -kv -lp 123 > /tmp/pipe; done
```

This works, but it only responds with the results from `secret.sh` the first time. Subsequent connections with the correct string don't get the expected response. I'm getting closer, however.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: try with `-l` *`(minus L)`* instead of `-1`.

Comment: The lack of `-l` was a typo. I had that in the actual command I was running. That's not the problem btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was the loop should not be on the command line, it needs to be inside the shell script. The command `read line` blocks until it recieves data from the listening port. All it needs is to be wrapped in a loop.

**Server**

```
mkfifo pipe
nc -lk 123 0<pipe | ./secret.sh 1>pipe
```

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    read line
    if [ "$line" == "open" ]; then
        echo "sesame"
    fi
done
```

**Client**

```
echo "open" | nc localhost 123
```

h/t to this the answer here, which I incorporated into the above.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269311/emulating-netcat-e